# How to use 以 in Literary Chinese?

Tags: grammar

For example:

> 差之毫厘，谬以千里

I understand the overall meaning of this saying, but if I wanted to just be able to define 以 as it is used here, how could I do so?

Answer (score 1):

以 = as; using; taking.

差之毫厘，谬以千里 = *to miss by a hair is as wrong as (to miss by a) thousand li*, or more to the point: miss by a hair, but (still) be off a mile.

Answer (score 1):

well,

i would suggest "thereby", "therefore", or "because of".

have a look:

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=以](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E4%BB%A5)

have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the characters "之" and "以" are "虛詞" serving mostly structural purposes.  We can shorten it as "差毫厘, 謬千里".

There are other meanings and usages of "以".  For example:

- 以卵擊石 - to "take" an egg and (attempt to) crush a rock
- 王往以眾 - the king went "leading" the crowd
- 以牛 - to "give" the cow (to someone)
- 用兵五十人以上 - sending a troop with 50 ppls or above